# Iterating through only persisted objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

This is the code for my create display:

```
def create
    @display = @department.displays.new(display_params)
    @token = @display.build_token(value: (max_token + 1) , status: 0)

    if @display.save
        ....
end
```

**max_token** is the method called to find the largest number of token in the display tokens.

```
def max_token
  @tokens = @department.displays.map do |display|
    display.token.value
  end
  @tokens.max
end
```

**Problem**

I've created a new display for the department with the code in the create method.

```
@display = @department.displays.new(display_params)
```

But it is not saved yet, as the **@display.save** is called only after the **max_token** method.

But when the **max_token** method is called, the code

```
@tokens = @department.displays.map do |display|
```

is also displaying the unsaved display of the department.

And since the token of the display has not been set yet, as it is not saved, throws a ***nil value*** error.

**My Solution**

This is what i've tried upto now, but I want to know if there's a better method.

```
def max_token
      @tokens = @department.displays.map do |display|
        if display.token.nil?
          display.token.value
        else
          0
        end
      end
      @tokens.max
    end
```

Comment: Is `value` supposed to be unique? If you're generating this at the app layer rather than in the database, you run the risk of collisions from simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not worried about the uniqueness of `value` at the DB layer, you can simply filter out displays with a `nil` value for `token`:

```rb
def max_token
  @department.displays.where.not(token: nil).map do |display|
    display.token.value
  end.max
end
```

(This is also assuming you don't actually need to assign `@tokens` as a side effect of `max_token`.)

Comment: Thanks, Was looking for something like this

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a new separated `Display` first then assign it to the `@department` after `max_token` get called so the new `Display` won't be included in `@department.displays.map`

```
def create
    @display = Displays.new(display_params)
    @token = @display.build_token(value: (max_token + 1) , status: 0)
    @department.displays << @display        

    if @display.save
        ....
end
```

Comment: I did try this. I was expecting some iteration method that filters out unsaved objects though. Thanks